# what should i do to be able to post multiple contents in my code in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my `serializers.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import product
 


class productSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= product
        fields="__all__"
```

views.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import productSerializer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

class productviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=product.objects.all()
    serializer_class=productSerializer
```

When i want to post multiple contents like this:

```
[
  {
     "Number": 1,
     "name": "1005001697316642",
     "image": "https://",
     "description": "fffffffff",
     "price": "USD 23.43",
     "buy": "https://"
  },
  {
     "Number": 2,
     "name": "1005002480978025",
     "image": "https://",
     "description": "dffdfdddddddddddddd",
     "price": "USD 0.89",
     "buy": "https://"
   }
 ]
```

I get this error:

> HTTP 400 Bad Request
>
> Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Vary: Accept
>
> {
> "non_field_errors": [
> "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."
> ] }

what should i do to be able to post multiple contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to overwrite the `create` method to allow multiple objects,
So we will overwrite it in the scope of the class that inherits `ModelViewSet`,
as shown below:

```
def create(self, request):
serialized = MovieTicketSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
if serialized.is_valid():
    serialized.save()
    return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```